# Bottleneck in the work place

Tags: colleagues

I am a junior developer in a big company. The team, which I am in, is developing a very old system (since 15 years). The system is very very specific to this team and only two people know much about it and only these two people assign a new task to me.

When I got a new task, I ask so many questions (not about my profession but about the system, in which I implement my component) in order to be able to make my tasks correctly but these two people are not answering the questions willingly and very slow when they are helping me, which slows me drastically. I have a feeling that they are only working for money, not more.

What would be the best advice to deal with these people or the best solution is finding a new job?

Comment: Well, legacy systems are a pain in the ass after all. How do you ask questions ? Do you mail them, do you interrupt them ? Some people react differently according to how you communicate with them.

Comment: I tried all the communication ways. When I try to communicate with them through e-mail or companys chat software, they do not respond at all. When I go to their rooms personally, they answer very unwillingly, which makes me mad. If they are hiring a junior developer, they should not expect that I know everything.

Comment: 15 years is a very old system?  We're still running CICS

Comment: Do you have a team leader or manager? CC him on everything so he's aware of where the bottleneck is

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If that system is 15 years old, then it is quite possible that the two remaining developers are working only for money. There is nothing particularly wrong with working only for money (although personally, I work for the sum of nice working environment plus interesting (fun) work plus money). After 15 years, they will be bored with it. In fifteen years time, you would also be bored with it.

So what you have to do first is take them as they are. You are not going to change them. Don't take it personally, don't get annoyed, it's not worth it. You do your thing, ignore what they are doing.

When you have a task, ask them, get whatever information you can get out of them, then you start searching the documentation (maybe you first have to search *for* the documentation), look through source code, learn what you need to learn, and add documentation as you go. If your boss asks what you are doing you don't say "I did X, but it took very, very long". You say "I did X, in order to do that I had to find out about A, B and C which I did; so I now understand A, B and C and they are properly documented so the next developer will have an easier job. "

Comment: Thank you very much for the great answer. I tried to do what you have suggested me but I have seen a single method, which consists of 1200 lines of code, and one of the very important variable is called "o" without documentation. Sometimes, I cannot differentiate whether I am not talented or the code is spaghetti.

Comment: @AdInfinitum If in doubt, blame the code

Comment: I think you are in a thought spot. I am a experienced developer. I changed job not long ago and the source code was in a terrible state: dynamic type variable with single letter name, function with 1000-2000 lines with all optional parameters, everything coupled, etc. My self-esteem and my motivation dropped. Surprisingly, not because it took more time than usual to complete any task but mainly because of the attitude "We've Always Done It That Way". Personally, what count the most is the attitude of the management and the team. I wish you good luck!

Comment: @SebastienDErrico I think I experience, what you have already experienced. I have read lots of literature and book about the "clean code" and now, in code reviews, they are forcing me to write a spaghetti code. Your comment relieved me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Pull your boss into this.  The other developers aren't budging, and it could be for many reasons.  Maybe you intimidate them (but if that's the case, they'd be intimidated by *any* junior developer at this point).  The reasons are not really your concern - that's for your boss to take up.  The *behavior*, on the other hand, is *also* for your boss to take up.

Share your concerns with your boss.  Mention the e-mails you've sent with no response, and ask the boss if it'd be prudent for you to CC or BCC him/her on these e-mails you're describing.  This leaves a paper trail.  After so much of this, and you're not getting the assistance you need, your boss will have something tangible by which to take some action.  When that occurs, watch out!  But believe it or not, this is easier than you trying to confront the developers directly.

Comment: At this point, I will try to make everyone happy by not pulling the boss into this problem but I think, it will not go on like that. I will try to make it in a good way but if it does not work still, I will follow your suggestions. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, people just don't like to be interrupted with questions.

Maybe you can gather all your questions together and schedule a meeting. Invite your boss and the other developers as well. That can be easier to accomplish.

Comment: I can understand that they may be interrupted with questions but I would be happy if a junior developer asks me questions to make his/her job better. This is a sign that he/she cares for the task. I am already gathering the questions but these questions arise new questions. Sometimes, it is impossible to think everything at once.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere no, I meant If I were a senior develop or a system architect, I would be happy if the junior developers ask me questions in order to learn me about the system, on which we are working.

Answer (score -1):

Every task you are assigned should have a priority level, an urgency level and a deadline. That's the only way you can multi-task anything and given the way these two to operate, probably the only way to get anything done.

As you follow up with requests for clarification, give them your best guess as to your progress of your task e.g. "this task was 15% done as of yesterday, I'd like to push the degree of completion beyond 15% today but this is contingent on you providing the answers to the questions I asked this morning" Hopefully, this lights a fire under their butts but frankly, as long as they know what their deadlines are and they take ownership for meeting the deadlines, their lack of responsiveness is their problem unless you are being held accountable for meeting deadlines no matter lethargic these two are. The important part is that you can point to a digital trail of communications that shows that you have been diligent in attempting to complete your task. CYA (*).

There is no need for you to comment on this site on their level of motivation - that's their problem.

Your problem is completing the tasks they have assigned you. Once they get your deliverables, they can do whatever they please with them so far as you are concerned.

(*) Cover Your Ass.

Comment: The company, I am working, is very wealthy and the monopoly in his area. Because of this reason, there is no something like "urgent" task. Everybody except for me is working loosely or I anticipate like that. In a such way that I cannot push them to help me by threathing deadlines. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @AdInfinitum - It's really, really out of your hands :) Heaven for me is working for a company that wins in the marketplace and competes as if its life depended on it - Google, AWS, Microsoft, Apple, Bloomberg are great examples. I guess if we want to know what Hell looks like, we should work for a company like yours - a monopoly that holds its part of the world by the balls and doesn't have to be responsive to anything. I'd be doomed to have a career failure working for such a company. My condolences to you.

Comment: A company like that would be a very good working place if I am waiting for my pension. However, I am at the beginning of my career and do not want to work only for money. I think in a short term, I cannot do anything but in a long term, I should consider for a company change. I accept your condolences :)

Comment: @AdInfinitum - Go crazy building up your skills set, and get the hell out of there before you become like your two seniors :)